# RichFaces 3 html tag inside commandLink

Tags: html, jsp, jsf, richfaces

We have a button setup in our application that looks something similar to the following:

```
<div class="button" onMouseOver="this.className='buttonHover'" onMouseOut="this.className='button'">
     <a href="#" onclick="callSomeAjaxSubmit();"><h2>Button Title</h2></a>
</div>
```

I'm trying to do the same thing with an `a4j:commandLink` tag, but it is not working properly.  here is the code I wrote:

```
<div class="button" onMouseOver="this.className='buttonHover'" onMouseOut="this.className='button'">
     <a4j:commandLink action="#{action.method}" id="buttonId">
          <h2>Button Title</h2>
     </a4j:commandLink>
</div>
```

The HTML that this renders is incorrect, and the `<h2>` tag ends up outside the `<a>` tag. Here is what is rendered:

```
<div class="button" onMouseOver="this.className='buttonHover'" onMouseOut="this.className='button'">
     <h2>Button Title</h2>
     <a name="myForm:buttonId" id="myForm:buttonId" onClick="A4J.AJAX.Submit........" href="#"></a>
</div>
```

The onclick is getting rendered correctly, and the link should work, but the `h2` tag needs to go inside the `a` tag in order for the button to render correctly on screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *The HTML that this renders is incorrect*

JSF doesn't render it that way. It's the webbrowser itself who interpreted the obtained HTML markup that way. You most likely looked in HTML DOM inspector in webbrowser's web developer toolset as available via F12, instead of straight in the raw HTML source as available via rightclick, *View Source*.

As to the why the webbrowser interpreted it like that; having a block [level element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements) like `<h2>` nested in an [inline element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Inline_elemente) like `<a>` is [invalid HTML](http://validator.w3.org). The webbrowser basically chokes on that and pushes the block level element outside any inline element in the HTML DOM tree.

Just swap them, and the browser will be happy.

```
<h2>
    <a4j:commandLink value="Button Title" action="#{action.method}" id="buttonId" />
</h2>
```